# CSS Strike Through in Inspector

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

Working on my site, I have fa icons, which should be black. They were black, then I changed my css file (then updated all the links on my html) and now my icons aren't showing up, and when I inspect the elements, I have a strike through the color:#000; part of my .fa-icon section. I tried !important, and the colour still isn't showing up. Any advice ?

```
.fa-icon {
  color: #000;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you (in the inspector) identify which selector that overrides your .fa-icon (is it your code, or some code that you include), by disabling properties using the small checkbox next to the properties ("color" in this case)?

Comment: you say that 'color:#fff' has a strike over it, but in your code you have 'color:#000', is that just a typo?

Comment: yes, #000 is black, and #fff is white, so if it's not showing up (if set to white), what colour is the background? (cos it wouldn't show up if both foreground and background are same...) If there's a strike through, then it's being overridden by css somewhere else.. you'd need to post the css file.

Comment: Yes sorry - typo ! I meant I have a strike through color: 000, not #fff

also my css file is absolutely massive. I've updated my post and here's my pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXbqxo

The icons are above the copyright info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually issue is font awesome cdn css which you imported in your css that is not working use below cdn path and check.

@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);

import this link into css file.

Answer (score 1):

a strike through the color:#fff; means that either the rule has been redefined after or has been defined previously by an !important; rule and can't be modified.  Go all the way up and down your inspector and you will find it.  Take into consideration overwrites at the element level by inline HTML css or javascript fuctions.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot through the inspector. I don't know what to look for